# Handlebars helper - object not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am iterating through an array controller to display items - and within this view I am trying to perform a custom Handlebar helper with the context of the current address - however within my helper, the object is undefined.

View:

```
{{#each temporaryUser.addresses}}
    {{#view App.AddressView addressBinding="this"}}
        {{addressActions view.address}}
        {{{view.address.display}}}
        <a {{action deleteAddress target="view"}} class="delete">Delete</a>
    {{/view}}
 {{/each}}

Handlebars.registerHelper('addressActions', function (address) {
    var display = '<div class="actions">';

    if (address.current && address.permanent) {
        display += '<p>This is my current residential, and permanent address:</p>';
    }
    else if (address.current && !address.permanent) {
        display += '<p>This is my current residential address:</p>';
        display += '<a href="#">Make permanent residential address</a>';
    }
    else if (!address.current && address.permanent) {
        display += '<p>This is my permanent address:</p>';
        display += '<a href="#">Make current residential address</a>';
    }
    else {
        display += '<a href="#">Make current residential address</a><br/>';
        display += '<a href="#">Make permanent residential address</a>';
    }
    display += '</div>';

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(display);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way a helper works. You need to fetch the context yourself from an options object:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('addressActions', function(path, options) {
  // passed context objects are stored in options.contexts
  // as you are only passing one context, it is the first one in the array
  var address = options.contexts.objectAt(0);
}
```

It works this way, since **you may be passing multiple contexts to your helper.**

Comment: Your way doesn't work. I got a similar helper working with: `Ember.Handlebars.helper('ternary', function(condition, a, b) {
  return condition === 'true' ? a : b;
});`, which I made up from combining various documentations...